# Oracle SQL grant privilege to fetch xml from a website

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to fetch data from a website in XML format, I added the website's certificate to the wallet.
the XML for example can be found here:
https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esummary.fcgi?db=taxonomy&id=273

When I try to get the data with SYSDBA user, I'm able to do it with:

```
select utl_http.request(
    'https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esummary.fcgi?db=taxonomy' || '&' || 'id=' || '273',
    '',
    '/my/path/to/wallet', 
    'my_wallet_password'
    )
from DUAL;
```

But when I try the same select from USER1 I get an error:

```
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1530
ORA-29024: Certificate validation failure
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 380
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1470
ORA-06512: at line 1
29273. 00000 -  "HTTP request failed"
*Cause:    The UTL_HTTP package failed to execute the HTTP request.
*Action:   Use get_detailed_sqlerrm to check the detailed error message.
           Fix the error and retry the HTTP request.
```

I know the problem is with privileges for sure because after giving all privileges to another user (TEST_USER) it worked for this user, but I couldn't find which privileges I need.
Privileges I tried to add:

```
grant execute on utl_http to USER1;
grant connect to SPU_RUN;

BEGIN
    DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.APPEND_HOST_ACE
    (
        HOST => '*.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov*',
        LOWER_PORT => NULL,
        UPPER_PORT => NULL,
        ACE => XS$ACE_TYPE(PRIVILEGE_LIST => xs$name_list('http'),
                             PRINCIPAL_NAME => 'USER1',
                         PRINCIPAL_TYPE => xs_acl.ptype_db
                   )
    );
END;

BEGIN
    DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL (
    acl => '/sys/acls/utl_tcp.xml',
    description => '',
    principal => 'USER1',
    is_grant => TRUE,
    privilege => 'connect',
    start_date => SYSTIMESTAMP,
    end_date => NULL);
END;

BEGIN
    DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE(
    acl => '/sys/acls/utl_tcp.xml',
    principal => 'USER1',
    is_grant => true,
    privilege => 'connect');
    COMMIT;
END;

BEGIN
    DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE(
    acl => '/sys/acls/utl_tcp.xml',
    principal => 'USER1',
    is_grant => true,
    privilege => 'resolve');
    COMMIT;
END;
```

I'm not a DBA so I'm sorry if i got it all wrong, but I still need to know which privilege is missing.
Thanks.

Comment: Looks like https://dba.stackexchange.com is a better place to ask